# Trying to manage content inside a Materialize Card

Tags: html, css, frontend, css-grid, materialize

First of all, thanks to you all for helping a lot of people!
Second of all, sorry for posting images in Spanish but I have no time to translate it into English. Anyway, text in photos are not relevant.

In this time I'm trying to develop and interactive degree program. Right now, it looks like this: 

[image]

My idea is to manage card to:

- Get same size on all cards
- Keep all content (top, middle and bottom) inside cards
- Manage middle content (name of a course in Spanish) to resize in favor to preserve card size

For example if i put 150% zoom, everything turn into this:

[image]

And if I put 50% zoom it looks about what I'm looking for:

[image]

I put a minimize snippet where you can reproduce two courses in one year.

```css
.row {
  margin-bottom: 0px !important;
}

#yearHolder {
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.col .s12 {
  padding-left: 0px !important;
  padding-right: 0px !important;
}



.card-content {
  padding-left: 10px !important;
  padding-right: 10px !important;
  padding-top: 8px !important;
  padding-bottom: 8px !important;
}

.card.small {
  height: 150px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="malla" class="row">
        <div id="1year" class="col l2 s6 offset-l1"><h6 class="center">First Year</h6>
            <div id="yearHolder" class="row">
                <div id="1semester" class="col s6">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <div class="card horizontal red">
                            <div class="card-stacked ">
                                <div class="card-tabs">
                                    <div class="col left">CBM-1000</div>
                                    <div class="col right">8</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-content">
                                    <h6 class="black-text text-flow center-align">Algebra y Geometría</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-tabs ">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col left">1</div>
                                        <div class="col right">12,13,15</div>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="2semester" class="col s6">
                    <div class="col s12">
                        <div class="card horizontal red">
                            <div class="card-stacked ">
                                <div class="card-tabs">
                                    <div class="col left">CBM-1010</div>
                                    <div class="col right">8</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-content">
                                    <h6 class="black-text text-flow center-align">Comunicación Elemental para la Ingenieria</h6>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-tab">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col left">1</div>
                                        <div class="col right">12,13,15</div>  
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Please advice me if I'm not asking in format to quickly fix in favor to get help**

Again, thanks to you all!

Answer (score 0):

Materialize widths should be left alone else this will happen. You seem to be overwriting the purpose of their grid system by using the !important feature. Also by targeting them in this way you will change the markup across your entire website which may not be desired. I would suggest adding a new class name to all those divs, then target your own made up classes.

Sizes:
Add a class to all divs called sameSizeCards
Css:

```
.sameSizeCards{

       Height: ______;

       Width: 100%; (let Materialize sort the width)

}
```

Text sizing:
Use @media queries to scale your text-size based on screen widths.

Answer (score 0):

[Materialize](https://materializecss.com/cards.html#sizes) provides three utility classes (small, medium and large) for cards that fix the height at 300px, 400px, and 500px respectively:

```
<div class="card small">
<!-- I will be 300px high -->
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/JjRVOgz